# DataTable search in not used field

Tags: angularjs, search, datatable, angular-datatables

I want to search in a datatable field that not used as columns in `serverSide` mode.

```
$scope.dtColumns = [

    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('title').withTitle('title')
      .renderWith((data, type, full) => {
            return `${data} <br> ${full.title_en}`;
         }
      )
]
```

I Have used `title` filed as a column, But don't have used `title_en`.

**Now When I search `title_en`, the result is empty!**

What's your idea?